# Google chrome extension and batch command

Tags: batch-file, google-chrome-extension

Is it possible to execute a batch command through Google Chrome Extension? I have tried this but Google Chrome seems to crash.

Answer (score 0):

Theres no way to execute batch files/executables from chrome/extensions as this would be a massive security risk.  The only way your going to be able to do such a thing is by making a plugin.  That said, there is an extension with a plugin that allows you to execute something from chrome...
http://www.chromeextensions.org/other/simple-get/
Be aware that this can be extremely dangerous and you should make it a private plugin and use manifest version 2 to try and protect yourself and your users.  Also, dont be surprised if Google doesnt allow an extension that uses this into their Gallery, good for your own personal use tho.